# What would be good foundations in order to approach manifolds considering an engineering formation?

Tags: soft-question, education, advice

I am currently studying control engineering on a sort of graduate level (mostly on my own).

However every book on the area mentions certain subjects or areas of mathematics (particularly manifolds and canonical forms) that seem too much for an electrical engineer who spent almost all part of it's career doing operational mathematics (integrals, derivatives, Fourier and Laplace transforms).

It is on my personal interest to bridge the theoretical gaps.

For example, **I want to get a better understanding of what is meant by *Sliding Manifold*.**

**My question in particular is, what would be the prerequisite knowledge in order to approach manifolds?**

Doing some research I've gather the next subjects (probably in poor order considering my formation):

1.- Real analysis

2.- Functional Analysis

3.- Abstract algebra

4.- Linear algebra (with focus on vector spaces)

5.- Topology , Differential Geometry
.
.
.
?

I'm sorry if I bother anyone with this question but I really want to learn more in depth to fill mental gaps.

Comment: Let me say that I am not familiar with this field, but since no one else has answered, I looked at *Sliding Modes in Control and Optimization* by Utkin to see what kinds of math are involved. I'm not sure if all treatments require the same level of background knowledge, but it appears that the main prerequisite is a background in dynamical systems. Certainly the first step is to learn basic analysis if you haven't already, but after that, judgng by the level of Utkin's book, you'll still have a good deal more work to do, perhaps equivalent to the better part of an undergraduate degree in math.

Comment: To make it easier to recommend books, could you describe your background knowledge in math? Please also say what languages you are able to read.

Comment: I'm able to understand english fairly well. Yes I've place a section of Utkin's book as an example of what I'm looking for, I will appreciate if you do recommend me some more books. But I have also seen for example integral manifolds and differential manifolds in other books like Xiaoming Hu's Analysis and Design of Nonlinear Control Systems. Yes you are correct there are still many gaps from undergraduate courses point me to basic analysis references if necessary please.

Comment: From where I'm from education tends not to be a good priority, so program structures of careers are not very well understood. I can read spanish and english. The courses I've taken are: Calculus, Vector calculus, Linear algebra, Differential equations, Fourier and Laplace transforms and Complex variables. All of these from a purely operational form and very poorly on proofs. Somehow I always kind of suspected that courses like Analysis were missing.

Comment: It is difficult to say what might be best for you, because you've already done so much but with little emphasis on proofs. I'm afraid that if I recommend an analysis book, you may find it either too easy and slow or too fast and difficult. A good introduction to analysis at an intermediate level of difficulty would be "Mathematical Analysis" (2nd ed.) by Tom Apostol. But if you find it's not at the right level, you can come back and ask for more recommendations based on your experience with that book. You should probably read about Riemann integration elsewhere before reading the chapter on...

Comment: Riemann-Stieltjes intgeration, though. For example, Burkill's *A First Course in Analysis* is also good and a little less abrupt on some subjects. After you have read a book on basic analysis, you should be able to better understand what you don't yet know. Certainly in your case a priority will be to study differential equations. The books of Pontryagin and Arnold are good for this. Russian books are often available in Spanish translation, so always check this. "Manifolds" themselves are a generalization of curves and surfaces in space, so this area belongs to differential geometry. However,

Comment: from what I was able to glean from looking at Utkin's book, the difficulties are more to do with dynamical systems. Good bibliographies for undergraduate topics can often be found by looking at the curriculum for the first three years of math at Cambridge.  https://www-wp.maths.cam.ac.uk/documents/schedules.pdf/ Lecture notes for some courses can be found here: https://www.maths.cam.ac.uk/undergrad/studentreps/tripos-specific-resources (The latest year of the schedules has some erroneous transpositions in the bibliographies between courses, but earlier years were correct and are online too.)

Comment: I really appreciate your help, you do really understand the problem I'm facing because in here we are forced to transition from undergraduate courses to graduate without a clue of the necessary background. I did read Tom Apostol's Analysis and like you said I found it slow and boring (not entirely because I was able to solve some exercises that got interesting) and then with abrupt changes,  I will check the material you suggested me and retake Apostol's book. Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: If Apsotol's book is too slow, you could instead start reading the second volume of *Mathematical Analysis* by Zorich. There you will see some basic facts about manifolds and vector calculus developed rigorously. It is a hard book, though (particularly the exercises). You can refer to the first volume any time you sense there is a gap in your knowledge.